# Removing special characters and numbers in sql table field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in sql server 2008 where a column contains field with string and special characters like
   abc;#34;pqr. Now I want a function to remove special characters and numbers from that field ;so the output would be like abcpqr.

Comment: Have u tried any thing yet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
    DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,(,),.,!,0-9]%'
      SET @str = '(remove) ~special~ 10 *characters. 3 5 from string 1 in sql!'
      WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
          SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')

      SELECT @str
```

[REFERENCE](http://dilipsinghdotnet.blogspot.in/2013/10/remove-special-characters-from-string.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use The following function

```
/*********************************
Removes any characters from 
@myString that do not meet the 
provided criteria.
*********************************/
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCharacters(@myString varchar(500), @validChars varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(500) AS
BEGIN

While @myString like '%[^' + @validChars + ']%'
Select @myString = replace(@myString,substring(@myString,patindex('%[^' + @validChars + ']%',@myString),1),'')

Return @myString
END
Go

Declare @testStr varchar(1000),
@i int

Set @i = 1
while @i < 255
Select 
@TestStr = isnull(@TestStr,'') + isnull(char(@i),''), 
@i = @i + 1

Select @TestStr
Select dbo.GetCharacters(@TestStr,'a-z')
Select dbo.GetCharacters(@TestStr,'0-9')
Select dbo.GetCharacters(@TestStr,'0-9a-z')
Select dbo.GetCharacters(@TestStr,'02468bferlki')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
DECLARE @var varchar(255) = 'abc;#34;pqr';

SELECT
CONVERT(varchar(255),( 
    SELECT CASE 
           WHEN ( ASCII(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@var, Number, 1)))  BETWEEN  65 and 90  )
           THEN SUBSTRING(@var, Number, 1)
           END
    FROM
    ( 
       Select top(255) number FROM [master]..spt_values
       where type = 'p'
    ) AS n
    WHERE Number <= LEN(@var)
    FOR XML PATH(''))) as Result
```

Result

```
abcpqr
```